# Check if string is empty or not

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

How can I check if a value is empty or not with XSL?
For example, if dadosis empty?

```
<Hoteis id="1">
        <codigo>458</codigo> 
        <morada>Porto</morada>
        <num_quartos>3</num_quartos>
        <piscina>Não</piscina>
        <restaurante> 
            <dados></dados>
            <num_mesas></num_mesas>
            <num_pessoas></num_pessoas>
            <hora_abertura></hora_abertura>
            <hora_fechar></hora_fechar>
        </restaurante>
</Hoteis>
```

For example:

```
<td align="center">
     <xsl:value-of select= "ns:restaurante" >
         <xsl:for-each select="/Hoteis/restaurante">
              <xsl:if teste="dados != ''">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                           <td align="center">Nº Pessoas</td>
                           <td align="center">Nº Mesas</td>
                           <td align="center">Hora Abertura</td>
                           <td align="center">Hora Fechar</td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ns:restaurante"/>
               </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:value-of>
 </td>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say get the length of the string and if it's equal to 0 then do x, else do something else. It's been years but I'll give the xpath a bash:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($yourElem) > 0">
```

Comment: Zero is false, so you could shorten that to: `<xsl:if test="string-length($yourElem)">`

Comment: Or shorten it further and just use `string($yourElem)` (see my answer for an example).

Comment: Not quite Daniel! Michael has beaten you to it as to why.

Comment: It's been 2+ years since I've even seen an XSLT script; not bad I remembered!

Comment: Actually, Daniel is correct that string-length() will behave the same way as string() in these circumstances. Whether that is the desired behavior is another matter.

Comment: I had some odd results when I tried it, hence falling back to checking the length but fair enough!

Answer (score 1):

Your method would work if you had used `test` instead of `teste` (unless you have a <strike>Spanish</strike> Portugese XSLT processor...?).

Personally, I prefer:

```
<xsl:if test="dados/text()">
```

Note that this test for the existence of a *text* node, child of `dados` - which is not necessarily the same thing as testing for `dados` being *empty*.

Comment: I try use like this but dont work                                    
                <xsl:value-of select= "/Hoteis/restaurante" >
                  <xsl:value-of select= "ns:dados" />
                  <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when teste="$dados/text() ">
                            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                                    <td align="center">Nº Pessoas</td>

Comment: <td align="center">Nº Mesas</td>
                                    <td align="center">Hora Abertura</td>
                                    <td align="center">Hora Fechar</td>
                                </tr> <xsl:apply-templates select="//ns:restaurante"/>
                    
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                Don't have restaurnt
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:value-of>

Comment: How can I get that data (num_mesas, num_pessoas, hora_abertura, hora_fechar)?

Comment: @user3689180 It does work for me when I use your example input: http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8s -- Also, please limit yourself to comments and clarifications; if you have questions that are not directly related to my answer, post them separately.

Comment: @user3689180 - In the code you're pasting in the comments you are using namespace prefixes. You should probably update your question with a more accurate example that reproduces the issue you're still seeing.

Answer (score 1):

What I prefer to use is `string()`.

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<Hoteis id="1">
    <codigo>458</codigo> 
    <morada>Porto</morada>
    <num_quartos>3</num_quartos>
    <piscina>Não</piscina>
    <restaurante> 
        <dados></dados>
        <num_mesas></num_mesas>
        <num_pessoas></num_pessoas>
        <hora_abertura></hora_abertura>
        <hora_fechar></hora_fechar>
    </restaurante>
</Hoteis>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:if test="string(restaurante/dados)">
            <xsl:text>"dados" is not empty.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(string(restaurante/dados))">
            <xsl:text>"dados" is empty.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
"dados" is empty.
```

Also, if you are using `xsl:strip-space`, and the element isn't listed in `xsl:preserve-space`, whitespace is ignored. For example, if `dados` only has whitespace (`<dados>  </dados>`), it will also show as empty.

Comment: "*If dados only has whitespace (`<dados> </dados>`), it will also show as empty.*" I believe you are mistaken about that.

Comment: It should also be noted that `string(restaurante/dados)` will return true if any *element* descendant of `dados` contains any text - although `dados` itself might be empty of any text nodes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Yes that's true about descendants containing text. I'm not mistaken about the whitespace though. (At least in Xalan, Saxon 6.5 and 9.5 HE/PE/EE.) Have you tried it?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I know why it always works for me. I'll update my answer with the caveat.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I clarified my answer. I use `xsl:strip-space` 99% of the time :-)

Comment: I see. For once someone posts an entire stylesheet, and I don't notice the settings, LOL.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - And I forgot not everyone uses the same settings I do. ;-)

Comment: Anyone help me on this?  http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8s/2 How can i get the data?

Comment: @user3689180 - Look at this version: http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8s/3 If this doesn't work for your actual data, you need to give us a better example. (For instance, why are you using the `ns:` namespace prefix in your stylesheet?)